# Windows equivalent of sl4a

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, sl4a

I'm teaching myself Python and have been experimenting with sl4a to interact with Android features like GPS and text to speech with codes like

```
import androidhelper

droid = androidhelper.Android()

location = droid.getLastKnownLocation().result

location = location.get('network', location.get('gps'))
```

and

```
import sl4a

droid = sl4a.Android()
droid.ttsSpeak("Hello World.")
```

I've been searching for a similar Python API module to access Windows 10 features on a PC but it seems to be much more complex.

Is there a relatively simply way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, magicandre1981.  I'll work on entering code properly.

Comment: If you're looking for an API recommendation, Software Recommendations SE is a better choice, but make sure you read their help center before posting because they have strict requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as TTS is concerned, use [gTTS](https://github.com/pndurette/gTTS).

For geolocation, use any of the tons of RESTful APIs like [FreeGeoIP](http://freegeoip.net/json/). Next parse the JSON returned and you're good to go!

Comment: Thanks for both helpful suggestions.